# Number of nodes in Hartree-Fock solution

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

The Hartree-Fock equation for atoms  is of the form

$\left(\frac{d}{dr^2}+f(r)-\epsilon\right)P(r)=g(r) \tag1$

Usually algorithms to solve this equation assumes that the number of nodes of $P(r)$, $n_r$, is of the form
$$n_r=n-l-1 \tag2$$

where $l$ is the orbital quantum number and $n$ the principal quantum number.
For closed shell $(1)$ is spherical symmetric so $(2)$ is justified.

What about non closed shell, what is the theoretical justification for $(2)$?

Comment: This may be of value:' On the Solution of the Hartree‐Fock Equation in Terms of Localized Orbitals', J. Chem. Phys. 34, 89 (1961); https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1731622 .